# Unable to access the Kubernetes Dashboard on Google Cloud Platform

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform

This is my first time of setting up Kubernetes on Google Cloud Platform.

**These are the steps I followed**:

I created an account on **Google Cloud Platform** and spun up a new instance:

```
https://console.cloud.google.com/compute
```

Installed the gcloud SDK:

```
curl https://sdk.cloud.google.com | bash
```

Configured my Google Cloud Platform account information

```
gcloud auth login
```

Installed the latest verion of Kubernetes

```
curl -sS https://get.k8s.io | bash
```

Launched a new cluster:

```
kubernetes/cluster/kube-up.sh
```

Confirmed that my configuration along with the cluster management credentials are stored in:

```
sudo nano /home/promisepreston/.kube/config
```

Installed kubectl on the server

```
curl -LO "https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/$(curl -s https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/stable.txt)/bin/linux/amd64/kubectl"
chmod +x ./kubectl
sudo mv ./kubectl /usr/local/bin/kubectl
```

Ran the command below which outputted the URL for the master services including DNS, UI, and monitoring

```
kubectl cluster-info
```

Deployed the Dashboard UI by running the following command:

```
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/dashboard/v2.0.0/aio/deploy/recommended.yaml
```

And finally, I tried accessing the Dashboard by running the following command:

```
kubectl proxy
```

Which should make the Dashboard available at:

```
http://localhost:8001/api/v1/namespaces/kubernetes-dashboard/services/https:kubernetes-dashboard:/proxy/
```

However, when I visit that URL I get error:

```
Unable to connect
```

And even when I try the command below:

```
curl http://localhost:8001/api
```

I get the error below:

```
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 8001: Connection refused
```

I have looked through a lot of documentation and tried multiple solutions, but none seems to work for me.

Comment: "Installed kubectl on the server" - why did you install it on the server? `kubectl` is a client, you need to have it on your machine. `curl http://localhost:8001/api` - do you perform this command on your machine? or server?

Comment: Or didn't know that `kubectl` is a client. I performed the `curl http://localhost:8001/api` on my machine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Installed kubectl on the server

You need `kubectl` on machine, from which you're going to access your cluster. If you installed it on the server and you ran `kubectl proxy` on the server - then you can access the proxy only from your server (depends on your network config).

If you do `curl http://localhost:8001/api` on the server - it will work.

So, you need to install `kubectl` on your machine, set up the k8s context for it and then run `kubectl proxy` - after that, all requests to proxy will be forwarded to your cluster.

In each request to k8s `API server` you need to be authenticated, when you run `kubectl proxy` - basically proxy will take care of authentication and SSL/TLS related stuff.

Read this for more info: [Use an HTTP Proxy to Access the Kubernetes API](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/extend-kubernetes/http-proxy-access-api/)
and [The Kubernetes API](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/kubernetes-api/)

[Configure Access to Multiple Clusters](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/configure-access-multiple-clusters/) - may also be useful

**Basically you need to do the following**:

**Note**: These should be done directly on your local machine, and not on the server or the terminal connecting to the server, but directly on your local machine:

Install the gcloud SDK:

```
# Add the Cloud SDK distribution URI as a package source
echo "deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/cloud.google.gpg] http://packages.cloud.google.com/apt cloud-sdk main" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-cloud-sdk.list

# Import the Google Cloud public key
curl https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg | sudo apt-key --keyring /usr/share/keyrings/cloud.google.gpg add -

# Update the package list and install the Cloud SDK
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install google-cloud-sdk
```

Configure your Google Cloud Platform account information:

```
gcloud auth login
```

Install Kubectl the Kubernetes command line tool:

```
curl -LO "https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/$(curl -s https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/stable.txt)/bin/linux/amd64/kubectl"
chmod +x ./kubectl
sudo mv ./kubectl /usr/local/bin/kubectl
```

Install Minikube that will be using to install Kubernetes on your local machine:

```
curl -LO https://storage.googleapis.com/minikube/releases/latest/minikube_latest_amd64.deb

sudo dpkg -i minikube_latest_amd64.deb
```

Start Minikube to pull the latest image of Kubenetes on your local system and configure it with Kubectl:

```
minikube start
```

If you already have some clusters set up, you can now use it to access your shiny new cluster:

```
kubectl get po -A
```

Minikube bundles the Kubernetes Dashboard, allowing you to get easily acclimated to your new environment:

```
minikube dashboard
```

Comment: Thank you. Trying it out now. Do I need to install Kubernetes on my local system as well?

Comment: No, if you need k8s for local development, you can try minikube or kind